# How to set kate voice for ios en-GB. in flutter - flutter_tts pub

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, text-to-speech

How to set kate voice for ios en-GB.

I m doing the below code but it's doing **Daniel**'s voice and I want to set **kete** voice for the same.

```
Future setLanguage({String value = 'en-US'}) async {
    var result = await objFlutterTts.isLanguageAvailable(value);
    print("setLanguageResult" + result.toString());
    await objFlutterTts.setLanguage(value);
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      await objFlutterTts.setSharedInstance(true);
      List all = await objFlutterTts.getVoices;
      objFlutterTts.setVoice(all[6]);
      print(all);
      printLog("setVoice " + value.toLowerCase() + "-x-afx#female_1-local");
    }
}
```

[image]

https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts/issues/174

Answer (score 1):

Voices are returned as objects. I had to convert to json and then decode from json:

`import 'dart:convert';`

`List<Object?> voices = await flutterTts.getVoices;`

`List<String> jsonVoices = voices.map((e) => jsonEncode(e)).toList();`

`List availVoices = jsonVoices.map((e) => jsonDecode(e)).toList();`

Then you can get the voice attributes - availVoices[0]['name'],  availVoices[0]['locale']

You set the voice with:

`flutterTts.setVoice({'name': availVoices[0]['name'], 'locale': availVoices[0]['locale']});`

Answer (score 0):

No need to encode/decode through Json like suggested by E G.

You can cast the result from getVoices :

```
List ttsVoices = await _textToSpeech.getVoices;
var availableVoices = ttsVoices.cast<Map>().map((e) => 
    e.cast<String,String>()).toList();
```

And select the one you need :

```
var selectedVoice = availableVoices.firstWhere((element) =>
    element['locale']!.contains('fr-FR'));
```